# Sum of reciprocals of the square roots of the first N Natural Numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt i}$$

This question was asked in an entrance test for an undergraduate program in India. I want to know how to approach such questions.

I was thinking of finding the partial sum till n and applying limit concepts to get an answer, but couldn't find such an expression.
I even tried limit of a sum method to convert it into an integral but was unable to do that as well.

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that the harmonic series $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{i}=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{i}$$is a divergent series (or a divergent limit in $N$ depending how you look at it)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an elementary proof of divergence,
note that

$\begin{array}\\
\sqrt{i+1}-\sqrt{i}
&=(\sqrt{i+1}-\sqrt{i})\dfrac{\sqrt{i+1}+\sqrt{i}}{\sqrt{i+1}+\sqrt{i}}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{i+1}+\sqrt{i}}\\
&<\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{i}}\\
\end{array}
$

so
$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{i}}
\gt 2(\sqrt{i+1}-\sqrt{i})
$.

Therefore
$\sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{i}}
\gt \sum_{i=1}^n2(\sqrt{i+1}-\sqrt{i})
=2(\sqrt{n+1}-1)
=2\sqrt{n}-2
$.

You can also get
an upper bound from this.

$\begin{array}\\
\sqrt{i+1}-\sqrt{i}
&=(\sqrt{i+1}-\sqrt{i})\dfrac{\sqrt{i+1}+\sqrt{i}}{\sqrt{i+1}+\sqrt{i}}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{i+1}+\sqrt{i}}\\
&>\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{i+1}}\\
\end{array}
$

so
$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{i+1}}
\lt 2(\sqrt{i+1}-\sqrt{i})
$
or
$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{i}}
\lt 2(\sqrt{i}-\sqrt{i-1})
$.

Therefore
$\sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{i}}
=1+\sum_{i=2}^n\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{i}}
\lt 1+\sum_{i=2}^n2(\sqrt{i}-\sqrt{i-1})
=1+2(\sqrt{n}-1)
=2\sqrt{n}-1
$.

Answer (score 1):

The sum diverges.  Its partial sums are larger than the harmonic series, which is know to diverge.

Comment: Check this:  Letting $n=100$, the sum is larger than $18$.

Comment: I will check the question again. I saw the integral test and this series does diverge according to that.

Comment: Is there a way to find the partial sum for this series. Like how would the approach be if n was finite?

Comment: See my answer for an elementary estimate that is within 1.

Answer (score 1):

Simply observe that
$$
\sum_{i=n}^{2n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} \geq (2n - n) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}} = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{2}} \to \infty,
$$
hence the series ( your sum ) diverges (is infinite).

Answer (score 0):

*Just added for your curiosity.*

In his answer, marty cohen gave nice upper and lower bounds for the partial sums in your specific problem.

If we make the problem more general $(k>1)$, 
$$S_n^{(k)}=\sum \frac 1 {\sqrt[k] n}=H_n^{\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)}$$ where appear the generalized harmonic numbers.

Using their asymptotics
$$S_n^{(k)}=\frac k{k-1} n^{(1-\frac 1k)}+\zeta \left(\frac{1}{k}\right)+\frac 1{2 n^{\frac 1k}}+O\left(\frac 1{ n^{(1+\frac 1k)}}\right)$$ where $\zeta \left(\frac{1}{k}\right)$ is a negative number which goes asymptotically to $-\frac 12$.